# Why am I getting a 400 Bad Request error with this code?

Tags: support, api, api-v2.2, javascript

I'm using this code (in an async function):

```js
let about = await fetch("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me?order=desc&access_token="+token+"&sort=reputation&site=gaming&filter=!)scMKI1zXS19EMMxEj7e");
console.log(about);
```

but I'm getting a 400 Bad Request error. I have gotten access, I have accepted the app and then recorded the `data.access_token`, which is what `token` is (I have checked that the token looks right, it is).

I used [this API help page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me) to generate it. I've spent a bunch of time trying to figure this out, but I can't even find any examples.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `access_token` is not enough; you need to specify a value for `key` as well. You can find it in the entry for your app [here](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/), this is how it looks like for one of mine:

[image]

I'm not sure how it works in JavaScript, but in cases like yours the API will send error details in the body; your library may ignore it by default if the HTTP code indicates an error, but it's still worth looking at.